# checking duplicate markers leaflet geoman

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet, leaflet-geoman, leaflet.pm

Im trying to check each geojson feature if it is a Marker. If it is I want to remove the placed layer then init drawing marker again.

If it is not the same position, I will just add it to the feature layer.

The problem is with eachLayer it always returns true because it loops trough all layers and it always return true because marker is added to feature. So it always repeats.

```
features.eachLayer(layer => {
  if(layer.pm._shape === 'Marker') {
    if(e.layer._latlng !== layer._latlng) { //This is never true, should be true if the placed marker is not placed over an existing features marker
      features.addLayer(e.layer);

    } else if(e.layer._latlng === layer._latlng) { //this elseif is always true for some reason and will loop
      map.removeLayer(e.layer)
      DrawUtil.addMarker(map, isSnapping); //Alias for pm.enableDraw.marker
      features.addLayer(e.layer);
    }
  }
})
```

Here is fiddle, my bad forgot to add vital code.
https://jsfiddle.net/2ftmy0bu/2/

Comment: I think you call this in the `pm:create` event, pls add the complete code. Also check if a layer is a Marker with `layer instanceof L.Marker` and if it is the same latlng with `e.layer.getLatLng().equals(layer.getLatLng())`. Please create a jsfiddle, it makes it easier to help

Comment: My bad. Added jsfiddle now. and yes, the code provided was called in pm:create

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
// listen to when a new layer is created
map.on('pm:create', function(e) {
    //should only place one marker each time

    // check if the layer with the same latlng exists
    var eq = features.getLayers().find(function(layer){
      if(layer instanceof L.Marker) {
                return layer.getLatLng().equals(e.layer.getLatLng())
      }else{
        return false;
      }
  }) !== undefined;

  if(!eq) {
    console.log('not equal')
    features.addLayer(e.layer);
    map.pm.disableDraw('Marker')
    //if marker is placed on the map and it is not placed on same place as another marker
  } else if(eq) {
    console.log('equal')
    //if marker is placed on the map over another marker, remove marker, then init draw marker again.
    map.removeLayer(e.layer);
    map.pm.enableDraw('Marker', {
      snappable: true,
      snapDistance: 20,
      finishOn: 'click' || 'mousedown',
    });
    // TODO: I think you don't want this
    //   features.addLayer(e.layer);
  }   
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/c6Lf758j/